# all goroutines are asleep - deadlock! with waitgroup

Tags: go

This is my code, where have I gone wrong?

```
func main() {
  intChan := make(chan int)
  wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

  for i := 0;i<5;i++{
    wg.Add(1)
    go send(intChan,i,&wg)
  }

  wg.Add(1)
  go get(intChan,&wg)
  wg.Wait()
  time.Sleep(5*time.Second)
  close(intChan)
}

func send(c chan int,index int,wg *sync.WaitGroup){
  defer func() {
    wg.Done()
  }()

  c <- index
}

func get(c chan int,wg *sync.WaitGroup){
  defer func() {
    wg.Done()
  }()

  for i := range c{
    fmt.Printf("%d\n",i)
  }
}
```

When I run this I get the error `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`

Here is error info:

```
goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0xc0000120d8)
    C:/Go/src/runtime/sema.go:56 +0x40
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0xc0000120d0)
    C:/Go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:130 +0x6b
main.main()
    F:/go/src/demo/channel.go:94 +0xf9

goroutine 10 [chan receive]:
main.get(0xc00001c120, 0xc0000120d0)
    F:/go/src/demo/channel.go:112 +0xe0
created by main.main
    F:/go/src/demo/channel.go:92 +0xeb
```

thanks for all,this is my first question.

Comment: `get` won't return until the channel is closed, and your main goroutine won't close the channel until `get` returns (because that's when it does the `wg.Done()`). That's your deadlock.

Comment: Also you capture i in the loop which can have any value from 0 to 4 each time send() runs.

Comment: Ignore above comment. The call to send captures i correctly.

Comment: @AndySchweig how can i fix it? i cant fix it.tks

Answer (score 1):

As Andy says in the comments you will only exit the `get` function when all of the inputs have been received and the channel is closed.  As you know there are five things to be received you could have a similar `for` loop to in the send:

```
func main() {
    intChan := make(chan int)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go send(intChan, i, &wg)
    }

    wg.Add(1)
    go get(intChan, &wg)
    wg.Wait()
    close(intChan)
}

func send(c chan int, index int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer func() {
        wg.Done()
    }()

    c <- index
}

func get(c chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer func() {
        wg.Done()
    }()

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        input := <- c
        fmt.Printf("%d\n", input)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/CB8HUKPBu2I

If you want to stick with ranging over the channel then you will have to close it when all of the messages have been sent which I would do by adding a second wait group:

```
func main() {
    intChan := make(chan int)
    allSent := sync.WaitGroup{}

    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        allSent.Add(1)
        go send(intChan, i, &allSent)
    }

    allReceived := sync.WaitGroup{}
    allReceived.Add(1)
    go get(intChan, &allReceived)

    allSent.Wait()
    close(intChan)
    allReceived.Wait()
}

func send(c chan int, index int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer func() {
        wg.Done()
    }()

    c <- index
}

func get(c chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer func() {
        wg.Done()
    }()

    for i := range c {
        fmt.Printf("%d\n", i)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/svFVrBdwmAc

Answer (score 0):

this can work!

```
func main() {
    intChan := make(chan int)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

    for i := 0;i<5;i++{
        wg.Add(1)
        go send(intChan,i,&wg)
    }

    wg.Add(1)
    go get(intChan,&wg)

    wg.Wait()
    close(intChan)
}

func send(c chan int,index int,wg *sync.WaitGroup){
    defer func() {
        wg.Done()
    }()

    c <- index
}

func get(c chan int,wg *sync.WaitGroup){
    defer func() {
        wg.Done()
    }()

    for {
        select {
            case i := <-c:
                fmt.Printf("%d\n",i)
            default:
                return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No it can't: https://play.golang.org/p/7ix3rRU4_OT the problem is that the default case in the select will be triggered when there is nothing in the c channel which as it is a blocking channel will probably happen after the first receive has taken place.  Then the get will exit after it's first receive because nothing new has been added to the channel and you are deadlocked again.